# Read C static structure in java

Tags: java, c, data-structures

I have a static structure in a c file like this one:

```
static struct my_structure[] = {

{ TE  , -1,    TEST,    0,       0, 0 },
{ RT  ,  1,       0,    0,       0, MSG( 670, "Test") },
{ RT  ,  2,      25,    0,       0, MSG(8187, "Test2"), MSG(1215, "Test3") }}
```

Is it possible to load the structure direct from java? Or how is the best approach to read the information in java objects?

Of course I can parse the file, but I would like to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Errr, is that valid C code? Where is the actual struct type definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use tools like [Java Native Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) to interface easily with C code, there are limits. One is that you need to declare the structure of `my_structure` in Java (JNA doesn't parse C code, it parses Java code which describes C code and structures). This means you always have to keep the two in sync.

Worse, different C compilers have different defaults when it comes to [alignment of fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Memory_byte_alignment_for_data_structures) in a structure (and many even have options to change those defaults). So a change in the compiler and/or the compiler options can break this brittle link.

That's why I suggest you write some C code which dumps the internal structure into a file which Java then can parse. To make things easier, you can use a [library which produces JSON](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) or maybe Google's [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Or solve the problem the same way on both ends and export the static structure into a file which then both the C and the Java code parse at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

1. The simplest and probably fastest: I converted this to JSON with some hardwired text replacing, and then interpreted the JSON with java. Java has very good json interpreting libs.
2. Alternately, you could compile the struct to a C object (or shredlib, or dll), write a JNI (java native interface) for that, and then read the data and interpret that. It will be a lot of work.
3. Alternatively, you could use a java lexical analysator for the job, for example [this](http://jflex.de/).

*Extension: (1) will be maybe impractical because of your C code uses macros. There is a mix between (1) and (2): you compile the struct with a little bit of helper code with prints the struct into stdout as JSON. Thank you for @UniversE for the idea!*

Comment: The JSON idea is good, but hard wired text replacing might not work, scince the OP is using macros. You need to write a little helper programm in C, which uses the struct and prints it's content as JSON to stdout. Then you can call this programm and use a pipe to read it from the java application.

Answer (score 1):

No, of course (?) it's not possible to load it "directly", what you have is C source code.

You're going to have to parse the code to figure out what it "means", especially since it seems to be using C preprocessor macros too (`TEST` and `MSG()` are likely macros).

Comment: lets leave the TEST and MSG aside. This could be saved in strings, that I can parse. From MSG(1215, "Test3") I need only "Test3".

Answer (score 0):

also you can try [JBBP library](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/) for Java and describe structure in its format and just parse and remap your data block from C to Java